# let $x_{n+1}=2x_n^2-1$ and $t=x_0$ then How many $t\in [-1,1]$ exist such that $x_{11}=1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> let $x_{n+1}=2x_n^2-1$ and $t=x_0$ then How many $t\in [-1,1]$ exist such that $x_{11}=1$ ?

my try ; if  $\cos x=t=x_0$ then we have $x_n=\cos(2^nx)$ and $x_{11}=\cos(2^{11}x)=1$ and also $2^{11}x=2k\pi$ now what ?

Comment: Excellent. Now compute all non-coterminal values of $x.$

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there

$$t = \cos x = \cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2^{10}}\right)$$

For each $k$ such that $0 \leq k \leq 2^{10}$ - this will give a unique $t$ - After which any value of $t$ obtained can be written as an already found value - hence there will be $2^{10}+1$ distinct values of $t$ corresponding to each $k$